# If $(X,T)$ and $(Y,T')$ are homemomorphic, and if $T$ is metrizable, does $T'$ metrizable ? Does the metric will be comparable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(Y,\mathcal T')$ two homeomorphic topological spaces.

Q1) If $\mathcal T$ is metrizable, will $\mathcal T'$ be also metrizable ?

Q2) If yes, does both metric will be comparable ? In the sense : there are $A$ and $B$ s.t. $$ Ad_X(x,y)\leq d_Y(f(x),f(y))\leq Bd_X(x,y),\tag{E}$$

where $f:X\to Y$ is an homeomorphism.

Q3) If $Y=X$, and $(X,\mathcal T)$ and $(X,\mathcal T')$ are homeomorphic and $\mathcal T$ is metrizable, then does the two metric will be comparable in the following sense ? There is $A$ and $B$ s.t. $$Ad_X(x,y)\leq d_Y(x,y)\leq Bd_X(x,y) \ \ ?\tag{F}$$

---

**Attempts**

1) I think it is since "homeomorphic" mean that there are the same. But I can't prove it. In fact, I know how to prove that a space is not metrizable, but I always have problem to prove that it is metrizable.

2) I really would say no, since $d_Y(f(x),f(y))\leq C d_X(x,y)$ would mean that $f$ is Lipschitz, and a priori, there is no reason for this. But maybe in some case it can happen, and if $f$ is Lipschitz, would $E$ hold ? I wouldn't be surprise that $f^{-1}$ would also be Lipschitz, and thus $(E)$ indeed hold. But in fact, I really have difficulty to prove it. May be it's not true ?

3) I know this work for normed vector spaces in finite dimension... as many property, this could fail in infinite dimension. If it indeed fail, would $(E)$ work in this case ? i.e. if $f:(X,\mathcal T)\to (X,\mathcal T')$ is a homeomorphism, then does $$Ad_X(x,y)\leq d_X(f(x),f(y))\leq Bd_X(x,y) \ \ ?$$

Comment: If $d_X$ is a metric on $X$ defining $\mathcal T$, then $d_Y (x,y) := d_X(\phi^{-1}(x),\phi^{-1}(y))$ will be a metric on $Y$ that defines $\mathcal T'$. Here, $\phi : X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1). As amsmath said, you can explicitly define the metric.

Q2 and Q3). No. Note that any strictly increasing, continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ will be a homeomorphism, and you can of course find such an $f$ with $\inf_{x < y} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = 0$ and $\sup_{x < y} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = +\infty$.

Comment: Don't regular implies hausdorff ?

Comment: @MSE I don't think so. The definition of "regular" is that for every closed set $C$ and every point $p \not \in C$, there are disjoint open sets $U,V$ with $C \subseteq U$ and $p \in V$. Consider the indiscrete topology on two points (or any number of points more than two). Clearly this space is not Hausdorff. Take any closed set $C$ and $p \not \in C$. Since $C = \emptyset$ or $C = X$, we must have $C = \emptyset$, but then we can take $U = \emptyset, V = X$

Comment: @mathworker21 Urysohn's Theorem states that all second countable regular (and $T_1$ if you're one of those people) spaces are metrizable. The converse does not hold. For example, take $L^\infty$. It's a Banach space, and hence metrizable, but it is not separable since there exist uncountable sets with no limit point, and so it is not second countable.

Comment: The book Topology of Munkres say that regular $\implies $ Hausdorf, and in Uryssohn metrization the just impose the space to be countable basis and regular (I just saw now). But indeed your example is interesting... because in the Munkres, they don't says that $U$ or $V$ are non empty (but they impose singleton to be closed... maybe it's equivalent ?)@mathworker21

Comment: @MSE Munkres does something which, after spending some time reading other topology books, I assume is not standard. What he does is require that all Hausdorff, regular, and normal spaces be $T_1$, that is, points must be closed in these spaces. It seems most people do not require this, and so you can have examples such as the one mathworker21 gave you. In my opinion, it's really an inane thing to do, but nonetheless that's what seems to be the case.

Comment: @D.Brogan : Ok, fine, thanks for your answer :) Could you please tel me in what the fact that singleton are closed, the counter example given by mathworker21 (to Regular $\implies $Hausdorff) is not a counter example ? Because I don't really get it.

Comment: @D.Brogan Ah, thanks. I was thinking first countable. In any event, amsmath's comment gives the answer to Q1